# DataView sorting alphabetically

Tags: c#

I am getting two inputs from the user. One is modalno and other is description and one add button if the user clicks the add button i goes and it should go and insert in the correct sorting order so far i have used this code in loadgrid()

```
DataView dv = ModelDataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "MODEL_NO";
grvModelNo.DataSource = dv;
grvModelNo.DataBind();
```

It is sorting correctly but my issue is :

```
modalno    description
1          test
45         test
455        test
50         test
```

'455' should insert after '50'  it is inserting before '50' it is checking first digit only i think.

Note: Here Modal_No is varchar()

Answer (score 3):

It is sorting as text, not as a number.  If you want  it to sort it as a number, you must present it as a number - cast it.

Why is it a varchar anyway, as it looks a lot like it will only be storing numbers...

Comment: With cast you mean that he should change the type of the DataColumn?

Comment: @Bobby - that was what my second statement lead to, that would be ideal, but may be too much of a breaking change...

Comment: Ah, I was just a little confused about that. Anyway, using number-types for numbers shouldn't be a breaking change. ;)

Comment: @Bobby - it shouldn't even be a question ;-)